# Facing issue in importing a large SQL dump

Tags: mysql, magento, mysql-workbench

I have a SQL file with 22 MB(The Magento table - "index_event") , when i'm trying to import it to the MySQL database using MySQLWorkBench , WorkBench is not responding and hence i'm not able to import it.

Have tried to split the statements manually but few of the insert statements are very large and is hard to split as they were single statements.

Can anyone please suggest on how to tackle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and connect MySQL using below command.

```
mysql -u youruser -p
```

Now select your database in which you want to import schema and data.

```
use your_db_name;
```

Now Provide you sql file using below command.

```
source /home/user/yourdb.sql;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Have tried that but it was displaying "Bash : Mysql command not found" , Have tried to set XAPTH and tried to execute the same visa mysql client using terminal window , SO was getting the error "MariaDB [(none)]> use magento
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'magento'
MariaDB [(none)]>"  DO you have idea on this?

Comment: make sure your user has permission to access that database